# How to add Phone authentication to an existing user account

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

how to add/change a users phone number for enabling phone authentication on firebase Auth?

All of the documentation seems to refer to creating a new userid for phone auth but then I would end up with 2 userids for the same user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to allow the user to sign in with two identity providers, you first create an account with one provider, then create an account with the other provider (e.g. [phone auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#create-a-phoneauthcredential-object)) and get the credentials from that, and finally [link the two accounts together](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/account-linking) into a single account.

Comment: So i would do this "Get the intermediate AuthCredential object:
If you need to get an AuthCredential object for the user's account, pass the verification code from the confirmation result and the verification code to PhoneAuthProvider.credential instead of calling confirm:" Then add this auth credential to the existing user account